# In Text Classification if I get similar performance with 100 features and 200 features, which model should I go ahead with?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, feature-selection, machine-learning-model, text-classification

I have built two text classifier models, one has 200 features the other has 100 features (reduced to 100 from 200 after feature selection). I see similar performances in both. Which model should I go ahead with for production?

Answer (score 4):

You should go with the simpler model, the one that needs fewer features. Fewer features means quicker training cycles, better interpretibility and a faster forward pass. All of these are important considerations if you would like to productionize your model.